# How do I send a jQuery AJAX request manually and do work while waiting for the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, optimization

I have a screen where different data is loaded in when a user clicks on different buttons. The following code shows how this is implemented.

```js
$([SOME BUTTON]).click(()=>{
    //Set up a loading screen
    let jqxhr = $.ajax([address])
        .done(()=>{
            //do some work
        .fail(()=> {
            //handle error
        })
        .always(()=>{
            //remove loading screen
        });
    });
```

I want to optimize this to send the request before setting up the loading screen and then await the result.

```js
$([SOME BUTTON]).click(()=>{
    let jqxhr = $.ajax([address]);
    //Set up a loading screen

    jqxhr.done(()=>{
            //do some work
        .fail(()=> {
            //handle error
        })
        .always(()=>{
            //remove loading screen
        });
    });
```

Is there a way I can implement this? As far as I can see there is no `.send()` function in jQuery's AJAX API.

I tried the second code snippet, but debugging showed that the request wasn't sending until after the loading screen was set up. Effectively the same as the original implementation. Is there is any `.send()`-type function or a way to send the request manually?

Comment: What you wrote should work. `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, it returns immediately after sending the request.

Comment: How did you use debugging to determine that it's not working?

Comment: I put a debugger statement just before jqxhr.done() and used Fiddler and to observe the requests. No request was made until the jqxhr.done() method was hit.

Comment: I can't think of a reason for that. It definitely calls `XMLHttpRequest.send()` when you call `$.ajax()`. `.done()` isn't called until the reply is received.